# RecyclerView with custom LayoutManager not show the scrollbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For some reasons, I need to custom a `LayoutManager` that implements the flowing layout item for `RecyclerView`. The code is:

```
public class FlowLayoutManager extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager implements
    RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider {

final static int LAYOUT_START = -1;
final static int LAYOUT_END = 1;

public static final int HORIZONTAL = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL;
public static final int VERTICAL = LinearLayout.VERTICAL;

public static final int INVALID_OFFSET = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

private static final int DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_SPACE = 12;
private static final int DEFAULT_VERTICAL_SPACE = 12;

@IntDef({HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL})
public @interface Orientation {
}

private SparseArray<Rect> mScrapRects;
private SparseIntArray mColumnCountOfRow;
private SparseArray<LayoutParams> mScrapSites;

private int mOffsetX;
private int mOffsetY;
private int mItemCount;
private int mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom;
private int mWidth, mHeight;

private int mTotalWidth;
private int mTotalHeight;
private int mScrollOffsetX;
private int mScrollOffsetY;

private int mVerticalSpace = DEFAULT_VERTICAL_SPACE;
private int mHorizontalSpace = DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_SPACE;

int mPendingScrollPositionOffset = INVALID_OFFSET;

@Orientation
private int mOrientation = VERTICAL;

private RecyclerView.Recycler mRecycler;
private RecyclerView.State mState;

public FlowLayoutManager() {
    this(VERTICAL);
}

public FlowLayoutManager(@Orientation int orientation) {
    this(orientation, DEFAULT_VERTICAL_SPACE, DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_SPACE);
}

public FlowLayoutManager(@Orientation int orientation, int verticalSpace, int horizontalSpace) {
    setOrientation(orientation);
    setSpace(verticalSpace, horizontalSpace);
    setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
}

public FlowLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    Properties properties = getProperties(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    setOrientation(properties.orientation);
    setReverseLayout(properties.reverseLayout);
    setStackFromEnd(properties.stackFromEnd);
    setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
}

public void setSpace(int verticalSpace, int horizontalSpace) {
    if (verticalSpace == mVerticalSpace && horizontalSpace == mHorizontalSpace) {
        return;
    }
    this.mVerticalSpace = verticalSpace;
    this.mHorizontalSpace = horizontalSpace;
    requestLayout();
}

public void setOrientation(@Orientation int orientation) {
    if (orientation == mOrientation) {
        return;
    }
    this.mOrientation = orientation;
    requestLayout();
}

public void setReverseLayout(boolean reverseLayout) {
}

public void setStackFromEnd(boolean stackFromEnd) {
}

@Orientation
public int getOrientation() {
    return mOrientation;
}

@Override
public LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

@Override
public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new LayoutParams(c, attrs);
}

@Override
public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {
    if (lp instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        return new LayoutParams((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) lp);
    } else {
        return new LayoutParams(lp);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
    return lp instanceof LayoutParams;
}

@Override
public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
    if (position >= getItemCount()) {
        return;
    }
    View view = findViewByPosition(position);
    if (view != null) {
        if (canScrollVertically()) {
            scrollVerticallyBy((int) (view.getY() - mTop), mRecycler, mState);
        } else if (canScrollHorizontally()) {
            scrollHorizontallyBy((int) (view.getX() - mLeft), mRecycler, mState);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
    LinearSmoothScroller scroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
    scroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(scroller);
}

@Override
public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
    final int direction = calculateScrollDirectionForPosition(targetPosition);
    PointF outVector = new PointF();
    if (direction == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    if (canScrollHorizontally()) {
        outVector.x = direction;
        outVector.y = 0;
    } else if (canScrollVertically()) {
        outVector.x = 0;
        outVector.y = direction;
    }
    return outVector;
}

@Override
public void onAdapterChanged(RecyclerView.Adapter oldAdapter, RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter) {
    mPendingScrollPositionOffset = INVALID_OFFSET;
    removeAllViews();
}

@Override
public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
    // mPendingScrollPositionOffset = INVALID_OFFSET;
}

@Override
public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    mRecycler = recycler;
    mState = state;
    mItemCount = getItemCount();
    if (mItemCount == 0) {
        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
        return;
    }
    if (getChildCount() == 0 && state.isPreLayout()) {
        return;
    }

    mScrapRects = new SparseArray<>(mItemCount);
    mScrapSites = new SparseArray<>(mItemCount);
    mColumnCountOfRow = new SparseIntArray();

    mScrollOffsetX = 0;
    mScrollOffsetY = 0;

    mWidth = getWidth();
    mHeight = getHeight();

    mLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    mTop = getPaddingTop();
    mRight = getPaddingRight();
    mBottom = getPaddingBottom();

    mOffsetX = mLeft;
    mOffsetY = mTop;

    detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
    if (canScrollVertically()) {
        mTotalHeight = calculateVerticalChildrenSites(recycler);
        scrollVerticallyBy(mPendingScrollPositionOffset, recycler, state);
    } else {
        mTotalWidth = calculateHorizontalChildrenSites(recycler);
        scrollHorizontallyBy(mPendingScrollPositionOffset, recycler, state);
    }
    // fillAndRecycleView(recycler, state);
}

private int calculateVerticalChildrenSites(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler) {
    final int[] maxRowHeight = {0};
    final int[] totalHeight = {0};
    final Point point = new Point();
    for (int i = 0; i < mItemCount; i++) {
        View scrap = recycler.getViewForPosition(i);

        addView(scrap);
        measureChildWithMargins(scrap, 0, 0);

        final int width = getDecoratedMeasurementHorizontal(scrap);
        final int height = getDecoratedMeasurementVertical(scrap);

        if (mOffsetX + width + mHorizontalSpace > mWidth - mRight) {
            mOffsetX = mLeft;
            mOffsetY += maxRowHeight[0] + (i == 0 ? 0 : mVerticalSpace);
            maxRowHeight[0] = 0;
            point.x = 0;
            point.y++;
        }
        maxRowHeight[0] = Math.max(height, maxRowHeight[0]);

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) scrap.getLayoutParams();
        lp.column = point.x++;
        lp.row = point.y;

        if (lp.column != 0) {
            mOffsetX += mHorizontalSpace;
        }

        mScrapSites.put(i, lp);
        mColumnCountOfRow.put(lp.row, lp.column + 1);

        Rect frame = mScrapRects.get(i);
        if (frame == null) {
            frame = new Rect();
        }
        frame.set(mOffsetX, mOffsetY, mOffsetX = mOffsetX + width, mOffsetY + height);
        mScrapRects.put(i, frame);

        totalHeight[0] = Math.max(totalHeight[0], mOffsetY + height);

        layoutDecoratedWithMargins(scrap, frame.left, frame.top, frame.right, frame.bottom);
    }
    return Math.max(totalHeight[0] - mTop, getVerticalSpace());
}

private int calculateHorizontalChildrenSites(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler) {
    final int[] maxColumnWidth = {0};
    final int[] totalWidth = {0};
    final Point point = new Point();
    for (int i = 0; i < mItemCount; i++) {
        View scrap = recycler.getViewForPosition(i);

        addView(scrap);
        measureChildWithMargins(scrap, 0, 0);

        final int width = getDecoratedMeasurementHorizontal(scrap);
        final int height = getDecoratedMeasurementVertical(scrap);

        if (mOffsetY + height + mVerticalSpace > mHeight - mBottom) {
            mOffsetY = mTop;
            mOffsetX += maxColumnWidth[0] + (i == 0 ? 0 : mHorizontalSpace);
            maxColumnWidth[0] = 0;
            point.x++;
            point.y = 0;
        }
        maxColumnWidth[0] = Math.max(width, maxColumnWidth[0]);

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) scrap.getLayoutParams();
        lp.column = point.x;
        lp.row = point.y++;

        if (lp.row != 0) {
            mOffsetY += mVerticalSpace;
        }

        mScrapSites.put(i, lp);
        mColumnCountOfRow.put(lp.row, lp.column + 1);

        Rect frame = mScrapRects.get(i);
        if (frame == null) {
            frame = new Rect();
        }
        frame.set(mOffsetX, mOffsetY, mOffsetX + width, mOffsetY = mOffsetY + height);
        mScrapRects.put(i, frame);

        totalWidth[0] = Math.max(totalWidth[0], mOffsetX + width);

        layoutDecoratedWithMargins(scrap, frame.left, frame.top, frame.right, frame.bottom);
    }
    return Math.max(totalWidth[0] - mLeft, getHorizontalSpace());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void fillAndRecycleView(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mItemCount == 0 || state.isPreLayout()) {
        return;
    }

    Rect displayFrame = canScrollVertically()
            ? new Rect(mLeft, mScrollOffsetY, mWidth, mScrollOffsetY + mHeight)
            : new Rect(mScrollOffsetX, mTop, mScrollOffsetX + mWidth, mHeight);

    for (int i = 0; i < mItemCount; i++) {
        Rect rect = mScrapRects.get(i);
        if (!Rect.intersects(displayFrame, rect)) {
            View scrap = getChildAt(i);
            if (scrap != null) {
                removeAndRecycleView(scrap, recycler);
            }
            return;
        }

        View scrap = recycler.getViewForPosition(i);
        addView(scrap);
        measureChildWithMargins(scrap, 0, 0);

        if (canScrollVertically()) {
            layoutDecoratedWithMargins(scrap, rect.left, rect.top - mScrollOffsetY, rect.right, rect.bottom - mScrollOffsetY);
        } else {
            layoutDecoratedWithMargins(scrap, rect.left - mScrollOffsetX, rect.top, rect.right - mScrollOffsetX, rect.bottom);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return mOrientation == VERTICAL;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
    return mOrientation == HORIZONTAL;
}

@Override
public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (dy == 0 || mItemCount == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int travel = dy;
    if (mScrollOffsetY + travel < 0) {
        travel = -mScrollOffsetY;
    } else if (mScrollOffsetY + travel > mTotalHeight - getVerticalSpace()) {//如果滑动到最底部
        travel = mTotalHeight - getVerticalSpace() - mScrollOffsetY;
    }

    mPendingScrollPositionOffset = (mScrollOffsetY += travel);

    offsetChildrenVertical(-travel);
    return travel;
}

@Override
public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (dx == 0 || mItemCount == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int travel = dx;
    if (mScrollOffsetX + travel < 0) {
        travel = -mScrollOffsetX;
    } else if (mScrollOffsetX + travel > mTotalWidth - getHorizontalSpace()) {//如果滑动到最底部
        travel = mTotalWidth - getHorizontalSpace() - mScrollOffsetX;
    }

    mPendingScrollPositionOffset = (mScrollOffsetX += travel);

    // detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);

    offsetChildrenHorizontal(-travel);
    // fillAndRecycleView(recycler, state);
    return travel;
}

@Nullable
public LayoutParams getLayoutParamsByPosition(int position) {
    return mScrapSites.get(position);
}

public int getRow(int position) {
    LayoutParams params = getLayoutParamsByPosition(position);
    return params != null ? params.row : 0;
}

public int getColumn(int position) {
    LayoutParams params = getLayoutParamsByPosition(position);
    return params != null ? params.column : 0;
}

public int getColumnCountOfRow(int row) {
    return mColumnCountOfRow.get(row, 1);
}

private int calculateScrollDirectionForPosition(int position) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return LAYOUT_START;
    }
    return position < getFirstChildPosition() ? LAYOUT_START : LAYOUT_END;
}

int getFirstChildPosition() {
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    return childCount == 0 ? 0 : getPosition(getChildAt(0));
}

private int getDecoratedMeasurementHorizontal(View view) {
    final LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    return getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) + params.leftMargin + params.rightMargin;
}

private int getDecoratedMeasurementVertical(View view) {
    final LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    return getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) + params.topMargin + params.bottomMargin;
}

private int getVerticalSpace() {
    return mHeight - mBottom - mTop;
}

private int getHorizontalSpace() {
    return mWidth - mLeft - mRight;
}

public static class LayoutParams extends RecyclerView.LayoutParams {

    //Current row in the grid
    public int row;
    //Current column in the grid
    public int column;

    public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
    }

    public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
    }

    public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams source) {
        super(source);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LayoutParams = {"
                + "width=" + width
                + ",height=" + height
                + ",row=" + row
                + ",column=" + column + "}";
    }
}
```

}

After that, set this `FlowlayoutManager` to a `RecyclerView`, then I found that the `RecyclerView` does not show the scrollbar, while setting the `LinearLayoutManager` it shows.

Here is the `RecyclerView` in xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

with a `400dp` height and scrollbars property.

The problem seems to be the `FlowLayoutManager` that I custom, but I really have no idea for this problem, could anyone help, thank anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of `RecyclerView` and `LinearLayoutManager` it seems that a custom LayoutManager has to implement these methods to show scrollbars:

- computeHorizontalScrollOffset / computeVerticalScrollOffset
- computeHorizontalScrollExtent / computeVerticalScrollExtent
- computeHorizontalScrollRange / computeVerticalScrollRange